# An Array of Soap Variables

Tags: php, laravel, soap

I am picking up some code (soap related) and I am not sure if its "best practice" I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
$requests = new stdClass();
$requests->rq = new stdClass();
$requests->rq->SessionId = $session;
$requests->rq->FareSourceCode = $searchs->fare_source_code;
$requests->rq->TravelerInfo = new stdClass();
$requests->rq->TravelerInfo->AirTravelers = new stdClass();
$parametersLike4LikeSector1[] = new SoapVar('M', XSD_STRING, null,null,'ns1:Gender');
$parametersLike4LikeSector1[] = new SoapVar('JOE', XSD_STRING, null, null,'ns1:PassengerFirstName');

$parametersLike4LikeSector1[] = new SoapVar('BLOGGS', XSD_STRING, null, null,'ns1:PassengerLastName');

$objectLike4Like[] = new SoapVar($parametersLike4LikeSector1, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null,'ns1:AirTraveler');

$requests->rq->TravelerInfo->AirTravelers = new SoapVar($objectLike4Like, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best Practice" depends on opinion. You will find a lot of code that works, some work better than other, but in the end you just need to find what works for you. We have a lot of developers working with us and they use SOAP parameters the same way you have it there.. you could also do

```
$params = array('apiParam1' => $someVariable, 'apiParam2' => $someVariable);
```

And then pass that array in the following call to the webservice:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, array('trace' => true, 'exceptions' => true);

$response = $client->__soapCall($apiMethod, array('parameters' => $params));
```

Some webservices have 'params' instead of 'parameters' in above call.

Hope this gives clarity